# Angle properties Ratio of Triangles

Tags: circles, angle

[image]

Given that $PX$ = 8.1 cm, $QX$ = 6.3 cm, $SX$ = 4.5 cm, $RX$ = 3.5 cm

Find ratio area of triangle $PQX$ : area of triangle $PSX$

What I've tried so far:
$PQX$:$SRX$ = 81:25
$QRX$:$PSX$ = 49:81

Took LCM
and got 3969:2025 = 49:25

The Answer Sheet states 
7:5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in this case since for the both the triangle base is on the same line and point P is common so height h will be common

$ \frac {ar(PQX)}{ar(SRX)} = \frac {\frac {1}{2}h.QX} {\frac {1}{2}h.SX}$
So ratio of areas will simply be ratio of bases i.e. $\frac {QX}{SX}$=$\frac{6.3}{4.5}$=$\frac{7}{5}$